# Proguard Issue When adding AIDL

Tags: android, proguard, aidl

I have create AIDL demo app. Adding proguard using **project.properties**. In
project.properties this file i am uncommenting below line

## proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

And Export apk is successfully but when running this apk getting aidl line error(Null-pointer exception) how to resolve this type of error?

Any line is required in "proguard-project.txt" in this file?

Comment: No! It is better to clean and rebuilt it before you export your project.